# Tire Size Road Bike

Tags: tire, size

I need new tires and not sure what size to order.  Here are photos of my bike tires.  I see 622x 15, but also see 25mm as a stand alone number.  622-25 seems more likely for my road bike, not sure if the 15 is correct.  Any help would be appreciated.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It's hard to read the label, but it appears to be saying that any width between 19 and 28 is OK.

Answer (score 10):

15 is the inside width of the rim in millimeters. The tire should be wider than that so that is stays on the rim. 19 to 28 mm in the second picture sounds like a realistic range of suitable tire widths for this rim, but in practice people have used 35mm cyclocross tires on rims like this without problems.

Comment: As to what OP should get: The same 622-25 tyres would be fine. If the frame and brake have enough clearance they could go up to 622-28.

Answer (score 0):

It is 15mm rim internal width,tire manufacture recommend max tire pressure 19-28mm tire, Tire size range you can choose should be 19-37mm,if it is compatible to your bike frame.